# Stuck on Launching subshell in virtual environment

Tags: python, subshell

I am trying to set up a bot on my raspberry pi using the directions in the read me file. The first step is to paste some code into terminal which I did. after a little while of it installing some things like python and the github files it ends with a few lines that look like this

```
Cloning into 'fairgame'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4524, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (26/26), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Total 4524 (delta 8), reused 12 (delta 4), pack-reused 4498
Receiving objects: 100% (4524/4524), 2.11 MiB | 195.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2953/2953), done.
Launching subshell in virtual environment.
```

Sorry I didnt think my post through
So heres the command I ran

````
'''shell


   `sudo apt update

> sudo apt upgrade
> sudo apt-get install -y build-essential tk-dev libreadline-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libxslt1-dev rustc libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms1-dev libopenjp2-7 libtiff5 libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev chromium-chromedriver
> 
> version=3.8.8
> 
> wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/Python-$version.tgz
> 
> tar zxf Python-$version.tgz
> cd Python-$version
> ./configure --enable-optimizations
> make -j4
> sudo make altinstall
> 
> cd ..
> 
> sudo python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip
> 
> git clone https://github.com/Hari-Nagarajan/fairgame
> cd fairgame/
> pip3 install pipenv
> export PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/.local/bin
> pipenv shell 
    > pipenv install
    > cp /usr/bin/chromedriver /home/$USER/.local/share/virtualenvs/fairgame-<RANDOMCHARS>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chromedriver_py/chromedriver_linux64
    > ```
    `
````

Its really just the install code (I think).

Comment: That's... a lot of stuff to paste into your terminal and run without understanding what it does. _Always_ be careful when running code you don't understand, and especially when it requires root access (if you see `sudo`, be extra careful).

Comment: In any case, it's probably the `pipenv shell` part that you're having trouble with. What happens if you `cd` into the project directory and run `pipenv shell`?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for all your help. When I run pipenv shell it comes back with `pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /home/pi/.local/share/virtualenvs/fairgame-3Td2oUte/bin/activate
pi@raspberrypi:~/fairgame $  . /home/pi/.local/share/virtualenvs/fairgame-3Td2oUte/bin/activate
(fairgame) pi@raspberrypi:~/fairgame $ `

Comment: Looks like you're good. From that new shell (prefixed with `(fairgame)`), try running the remaining commands in your script, starting with `pipenv install`.

Comment: @Chris I'm getting the error `bash: RANDOMCHARS: No such file or directory` When running `cp /usr/bin/chromedriver /home/$USER/.local/share/virtualenvs/fairgame-<RANDOMCHARS>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chromedriver_py/chromedriver_linux64` Thanks again for all your help

Comment: Well, do you have the Chrome driver installed?

Comment: @Chris yes, but for some reason it did not install to /usr/bin/chromedriver which I think is where the program is looking for it. How to I move it there or make the make the script find it (assuming the location is actually the issue). I also relized that I didnt have actual google chrome install but rather I was running on chromium which might also have something to do with it.

Comment: No, the `cp` command copies it _from_ there. Just change it to copy from wherever yours is.